# About the hash key for SMS Retriever API

Tags: android, api, authentication, sms

I have created a hash key for use with the SMS Retriever API.
But the key is included in the incoming SMS text.
(ex: <#> auth number is [1111] **OcrEAP9yxkZ**)

I wonder if there is a **security issue** if I see this key.
Or is there a way to subtract the hash key from the SMS incoming message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant remove hash key from the message. That is the only way for play services to determine the app which owns the message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are there any security issues?

Comment: No because the authentic handler for that message is only your app. So play services will deliver that message to your app only.

Comment: Thanks so much, Vishal Arora. have a nice day.

Comment: How can i do finish the this answer? Sorry, But I am StackOverflow is first time.

Comment: but the key added in sms can be used any place to send otp It will miss lead

Comment: Parsing of the message send to your app should take care of filtering out spams.